# Avoiding void* in C++

Tags: c++

I have an application that requires the packing of heterogeneous data in to a single structure.  For example, a single structure might contain three floats, two integers and a string.  I don't know which fields I'll have until runtime, and the key requirement is that the process be extremely fast.  I was planning to use an array of void*, which I can cast to the appropriate type when the message reaches its destination, but is there a better way of doing this?  Perhaps using Boost?

Comment: Do you have any bounds on what content you will receive? Number of types, number of elements, anything?

Comment: Abstract class with type id and inheritance?

Comment: Boost.Any/Boost.Variant?

Comment: If the types of data being stored is limited to basic data types, something where you have an array of ints, array of doubles, etc., and they only get initialized when a value is registered with the object?  `bool registerInt(int val, string key)`, or something like that?  You could use void* as the type of last resort (objects or anything else that doesn't quite fit in properly).

Comment: Kerrek: The data will usually consist of a set of floats or ints, occassionally there will be a string as well.  The problem is a slightly strange one, as I will only receive ONE message every time the program is run, and the format of that message is exactly known beforehand, but I don't want to recompile the program before I receive each message.  I guess I could use the metadata (it's xml) to build a custom C++ parser every time the program runs, and which issues its action to a known interface.  I hadn't thought about it that way.

Comment: Matteo: grazie mille, I will check those types out (I'm using Boost for just about the first time, I've been away from C++ for many years).

Comment: is it really necessary that your struct holds its data as actual members? If not, it could hold a `const double*`, a `const int*` and a  `const std::string*` (plus some integer counts), which point to the actual data hold elsewhere (and dynamically allocated at runtime.)

Comment: How does the producer you know what to pack, and how does the consumer know what (they want) to unpack?  How many different combinations of types do you need to support?

Comment: Walter: no, and that's the line I was going down with the void* approach.

Comment: Tom: the message is self-describing, so each data item is prefixed with the type that it represents.  The list of types appears to be: float, short, long, double, int, bool and a "YES/NO/NA" indicator, the last two of which I suppose I could massage in to a numerical data type...  I could have sworn I needed to support strings, but if I don't then that makes life so much simpler.  Time to check the documentation again.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps boost_variant will satisfy your needs?

http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the plain old [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Could, but it's not safe and too restricted (requires POD). Might as well use `variant`.

Comment: @GMan I'm fully aware of that, however OP said: *"the key requirement is that the process be extremely fast"*. In such circumstances, it is not completely unreasonable to trade some safety and convenience in exchange for performance.

Comment: Perhaps, but always last though. If a person asks "Can I do X, and fast?" I always completely disregard the "fast" part, because fast is only sensible in a context where the program is correct, and you don't get a correct program by worrying about micro-optimizations.

Comment: The program does need to be correct, obviously, but fast is an equal requirement.  The current C# version runs in around 12ms, which is around 11,700us too slow, hence the bonkers stay-up-all-night-and-rewrite-in-c++ that I'm currently undertaking :-)

Comment: @endian: That's fine, but your next step should be a correct C++ version, from C#, *then* a fast C++ version.

Comment: @GMan It is sometimes impossible to think about correctness alone and then hope to magically "slap on" some performance in the end. Sometimes, you have to consider both in advance. And sometimes, you even have to include micro-optimizations in your thinking. For example, I had a case where I specifically tailored a data structure to work well with a specific x86 instruction. These kinds of situations are very rare of course, but not completely non-existent...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to define a interface called Data. This Interface did not provide anything except a virtual destructor. 
All my data-types now inherit from the Data interface. This allows me to define a vector of Data pointers. When I need them I cast them to the actual type, so that I can use them.

This solution avoids the use of void Pointers, by using a marker class instead.

```
// Marker interface
class Data {
     public:
           virtual ~Data()=0;
}
// Own Datatype
class MyDataType: public Data {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think with that solution I would have the overhead of creating objects to hold the values, and I can't afford that kind of delay.

Comment: Is this the same problem? endian said that the content (data members) of his struct are unknown at compile time ...

Comment: We do also not know our datatypes at compile time, therefore we cast them to Data and then make dynamic cast back to the type needed at runtime (while ensuring that this cast works). So we can store datatypes pointing to Data instead of storing something pointing to a specific datatype.

Comment: @endian: How do you know this delay is such that you can't afford it? How can you profile code that doesn't exist? Stop worrying about speed. This is 2011, even the dumbest programs run fast enough. Make your program *work* first. Otherwise I write the fastest of them all: `int main(){}`.

Comment: @GMan: As I've just written in response to another commenter, the current, working C# version of the code runs in 12ms - only around 11,700us of performance left to find...

Comment: @endian we have about 500000 cast per second, and this is definitively not our bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks tune2fs, so approximately 2 us per cast, I will have to do some benchmarking and see what's what.